# jquery-Flot using <Div> with % width and height

Tags: jquery, css, html, flot

I am using Flot Jquery library, 
I want to set the placeholder div dimension (height and width) in % 
`<div id="placeholderYear" style="width:50%;height:30%;"></div>`

But I get always the exception: 
"JavaScript runtime error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 360, height = 0"

How can I fix it?
Thanks,Nk

Comment: we need more code, from all the elements .

Comment: The placeholder div is 30% of what?  My guess would be 30% of nothing, so (0.30 * 0 = 0).

Answer (score 2):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/waki/JwpHj/1/)
I think problem with css style and need two div, like

`<div class="demo-container">
    <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
</div>`

Comment: Is it possible to use responsive bootsrap on the chart? (scale the chart)

Comment: like this http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/navigate/index.html ? (panning and zooming) or i misunderstood?

Comment: I need something like this:
[link] http://bootstrapmaster.com/live/acme2/charts-flot.html
(resize the chart with page dimension)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/waki/JwpHj/2/ with flot plugin, but height can't be set in percent.

Comment: Worked like a charm!